# Giving file permissions(rwx) using shell command java

Tags: java, file, shell, permissions, command

I have a xml file in linux which has only read permission initially. I need to update the file content. So am trying to give file permissions(wx) through java.

Here is the code:

```
File pomFile = new File(wsPath + "pom.xml");

logger.info("Before change: Is Execute allow : " + pomFile.canExecute());  //false
logger.info("Before change: Is Write allow : " + pomFile.canWrite());   //false
logger.info("Before change: Is Read allow : " + pomFile.canRead());   //true

String command = "sudo chmod -R ugo+wx " + wsPath + "pom.xml";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

logger.info("After change: Is Execute allow : " + pomFile.canExecute());  //false
logger.info("After change: Is Write allow : " + pomFile.canWrite());   //false
logger.info("After change: Is Read allow : " + pomFile.canRead());   //true

InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/output-pom.xml");
String packageName=AppConstants.PACKAGE_DEFAULT+"."+client+"."+projectName;
String pomContent=IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
pomContent=pomContent.replace("<groupId>PACKAGE_NAME</groupId>","<groupId>"+packageName+"</groupId>");
pomContent=pomContent.replace("PROJECT_NAME", projectName);

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(pomFile, false);
writer.write(pomContent);
writer.close();
```

After setting permission also, pomFile.canWrite() and pomFile.canExecute() shows false.
Also FileWriter is throwing exception. What could be the solution for this?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: wsPath/pom.xml (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.apptium.eportal.servlet.CreateProjectServlet.doPost(CreateProjectServlet.java:179) ~[classes/:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:189) [logback-access-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [catalina.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.32]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: Did you check the exit code of p? What does it say? You need execute permission for the parent dir in order to change the permissions of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
pomFile.setWritable(true);
pomFile.setExecutable(false);
pomFile.setReadable(false);
```

Alternatively you can try this as Java IO classes do not have a readymade method for the same

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 file");
```

If you are using Java7, then you can use

```
setPosixFilePermissions(Path path, Set perms)

// Example code 

Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
//add owners permission
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
//add group permissions
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
//add others permissions
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);

Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get(wsPath + "pom.xml"), perms);
```

Comment: Or, more succinctly, `Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx");` or even `Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = EnumSet.allOf(PosixFilePermission.class);`.